# Add onClick programmatically to imageview

Tags: android, onclick, imageview

In XML I have `android:onClick="deleteRow"` which works fine, but now I need to add this method programmatically. Here is code:

XML:

```
            <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="50px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/delete"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="deleteRow"
            android:layout_column="1" />
```

deleteRow function

```
public void deleteRow(View v){
    // get row that is parent of clicked img
    View row = (View) v.getParent();
    // get rows container
    ViewGroup container = ((ViewGroup)row.getParent());
    // delete the row and invalidate view so it gets redrawn
    container.removeView(row);
    container.invalidate();
}
```

Adding imageView programmatically

```
// Set params for new deleteimage
TableRow.LayoutParams imgParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, 50, 1);

ImageView deleteAns = new ImageView(this);
deleteAns.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
tr.addView(deleteAns, imgParams);
```

Comment: try `setOnClickListener`maybe?

Comment: Please don't add the answer to the post. Either accept the answer that helped you or create your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // your code
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    deleteAns.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
               deleteRow(view);
                    }});
```